# Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle ORA-12170:TNS:Connect Timeout Occur

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, ora-12170

Good day,

Would like to ask help for my problem on  MS office 2007 add-ins on oracle 11g database.
the problem is I have an add-ins in msoffice 2007 which connect and insert data on oracle11g db.
error is what the title said.
the error occured after upgrading the windows machine from 8.1 32bit to 10 65 bit.
reverting it to 8.1 32bit did not solve the problem.
Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v0dZ.png)

here are some of the
required software that needs to be install before using it.
Oracle11g client 32bit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzzwy.png)
oracle11g odbc
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjhvw.png)
sqlnet ora / tnsnames ora
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usrFp.png)

Reinstalling everything as per our documented manual did not solve the problem.
firewall are also down.

hope someone can help me here

Thank you!